# MySQL: calculating cart line items + sum of options with individual values

Tags: mysql, sql

Working in MySQL, if it makes a difference: I'm looking for a set-based solution for calculating a total of a one-to-many relationship (yes, I'm writing my own shopping cart, because reasons), and I'd rather not loop a temp table if I can avoid it. Two cart tables are in play:

```sql
create table cartItems (idkey int auto_increment,
idlineitem int,
itemDesc varchar(50),
price decimal,
qty int
, primary key(idkey));

create table cartItemsOptions (idkey int auto_increment,
idlineitem int,
optionPrice decimal,
optionPct decimal,
optionDesc varchar(50)
, primary key(idkey));

insert into cartItems (idlineitem, itemdesc, price, qty)
values (1, 'Shirt', 30.00, 2);
insert into cartItems (idlineitem, itemdesc, price, qty)
values (2, 'Pants', 40.00, 2);
insert into cartItems (idlineitem, itemdesc, price, qty)
values (3, 'Socks', 10.00, 2);

insert into cartItemsOptions (idlineitem, optionPrice, optionPct, optionDesc)
values(1, 0, 0, 'color:red');
insert into cartItemsOptions (idlineitem, optionPrice, optionPct, optionDesc)
values(1, 10.00, 0, 'size:2XL');
insert into cartItemsOptions (idlineitem, optionPrice, optionPct, optionDesc)
values(1, 10.00, 0, 'Monogram');

insert into cartItemsOptions (idlineitem, optionPrice, optionPct, optionDesc)
values(2, 0, 0, 'hemming');
insert into cartItemsOptions (idlineitem, optionPrice, optionPct, optionDesc)
values(2, 0, 0, 'size:38R');
insert into cartItemsOptions (idlineitem, optionPrice, optionPct, optionDesc)
values(2, 0, 0, 'color:black');

insert into cartItemsOptions (idlineitem, optionPrice, optionPct, optionDesc)
values(3, 0, 10, 'fibre:silk');
insert into cartItemsOptions (idlineitem, optionPrice, optionPct, optionDesc)
values(3, 0, 0, 'color:black');

-- select everything, no math
select i.*, o.* 
from cartItems i
inner join cartItemsOptions o
on i.idlineitem = o.idlineitem;
```

The goal is to calculate the cart total with a set operation instead of a loop. I can't wrap my mind how to do this without looping a temp table. In PHP this would be relatively trivial, but I'd like to keep this in SQL if possible.

In the shirt example, an arbitrary price is assigned to two of the options.

In the socks example, one option is a percentage of the product price.

Desired output, simplified to focus on the numbers:

```
# itemDescr, price     example_formula
Shirt        100.00    (30 + 10 + 10) * 2
Pants         80.00    (30 + 0 + 0) * 2
Socks         22.00    (10 + 0 + (10 * .1)) * 2
```

Comment: Please provide actual sample from both tables, along with the desired results.

Comment: I don't understand. What is unclear about my example above?

Comment: For me, I can't understand how the data that you show relates to your tables. It is also quite unclear which result you expect. Providng your data and results as tabular text would make it easier to understand.

Comment: Providing create table statements and insert statements to populate the tables also makes it a lot easier for people to work with the data to try to help you.

Comment: Note that price is rarely FLOAT; it's why DECIMAL was invented. For further help, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Got it. Edit the question, or post new?

Comment: @BillinKansasCity: no answers were posted yet. You can edit your question.